# python switching boolean between classes

Tags: python

Is it possible to switch boolean statements between classes?
I'm having issues with it. Ive tried passing through self in the tester function, but cant seem to make it work.

```
class bolt():
    thing = False
    def tester():
        thing = True
class classtwo():
    bolt.tester()
    if bolt.thing:
        print("True")
    elif not bolt.thing:
        print("False")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure that's what you want, but we never know :

```
class bolt():
    def __init__(self):
        self.thing = False
    def tester(self):
        self.thing = True
        
class classtwo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_bolt = bolt()
        self.my_bolt.tester()
        if self.my_bolt.thing:
            print("True")
        elif not bolt.thing:
            print("False")
classtwo()
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `bolt.thing = True`.

class `bolt()` is not instantiated anywhere to have its own attributes and methods. The class is static and global and accessible publicly.